# Visual Studio Jupyter notebook

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, insert

When I want to work in a kernel of my Jupiter notebook open in Visual Studio, I have to type "I" to write something. If I don't do that and I start to write my code, nothing happened and sometimes it's clear the content of my kernel. Do you know why I have to type "I" and why can I no directly write my code?

Comment: Is your Visual Studio Code bound to vim? In vim you can edit after you press i or insert

Comment: Yes! It was but now I have uninstalled it and I don't need anymore to type I. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help! I have written a short answer for future visitors who may have the same problem. If you accept it as the correct answer, then we are automatically helping any future visitors who have the same problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Visual Studio Code was bound to vim. After uninstalling it, the problem was solved.